# Can't change language in botframework

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I created a bot in botframework (microsoft Azure) connect to a LUIS App. It worked all very well. But in english. The connection between the Bot and LUIS App has been done automatically.

Now I want it to work in German. So I created a new App in luis with de-de culture. Created my german intents. Published it.

I followed the instructions from [LUISChatBot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample). I could retrieve LUIS AppID and Authorizing Key as well as the endpoint of the German LUIS App to add it to my Azure chat bot. And the bot continues to understand only the intents in english!

So I guess the connection doesn't work how it is explained in the instructions above. Even worse : even if I put nothing ( = I remove the ID and Key and let it empty) in LuisAPIkey or LuisAPIId represented in the [image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#connect-your-luis-app-to-the-bot) of the Azure Chatbot settings, the bot continues to understand the english intents !?!

How can I make it work? I looked in the code of the bot, but I don't find the key appearing there (which makes sense). The only think I found, was in BasicLuisDialog.cs :

```
public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIKey"], 
        domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIHostName"])))
    {
    }
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Could you be more specific about "I put NOTHING in LuisAPIkey or LuisAPIId"? It seems to me that the key-s are taken from other place by the bot..

Comment: Check out this link regarding multiple apps in different languages: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-resources- faq#language-and-translation-support". Does this help?

Comment: Well not really. I now managed to make it work by using the same regions in Azure and EU.luis. But I don't understand why it continues working when I remove the key and endpoint of LUIS in Azure. But that is not sooo important..

Answer (score 0):

Half-Answer : I could change the language by changing the region in Azure (west EU) and then also use eu.luis.ai.

But I still don't know why the chatbot continued working when I removed the key and endpoint of LUIS in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var english = new Option();
english.Locale = "en-US";
```

Reference: [GitHub](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot/blob/master/ChooseLanguageBot/Dialogs/LanguageChoiceDialog.cs)

or

In BotSDK v4.0, you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");` to translate your existing language to the language you needed.